# Matching csv of postal (zip) codes to another shapefile

Tags: arcgis-desktop, csv, attribute-joins

I have a csv of survey results and each participant supplied their postal code. I also have a shapefile (polygon) that is the area of each postal code. I'm trying to get the csv answers (one point for every participant) to be displayed within the boundaries of the polygon.

I'm not concerned where inside the appropriate polygon just that they are within the bounds. I am unable to use geocoding at this moment and thought some sort of join/merge would work.

Comment: Does it matter if all the points are in the exact same location?

Comment: Nope, I just need them to be within the area.

Comment: If you have advanced license you could join your csv to your polygons, then convert polygons to points using Feature to Point or Feature Vertices to Point

Comment: Will this force a one-to-one join? Ideally there will be a bunch of points in the same place based on postal code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing I figured it out.

I converted the polygons to points, added XY coordinates to their table, them joined those points to the CSV.

After this join I could add my CSV points as XY data and each point was within the polygons.